# OpenTelemetry .NET Core Autoinstrumentation - Correlate logs via traceid propagation?

Tags: .net-core, open-telemetry

Is it even possible to use an autoinstrumentation tracer while also enriching logs with the trace information?  The goal is to correlate them at destination by the traceparent or span info.  My guess is at this point might simply be through manual instrumentation.  Any experience you may have would help.  Thanks.